# In Interaction Studio, is there a way to get hold of the referral source for the current session from within a listener in the Sitemap JS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, evergage, interaction-studio

This is what a stripped down version of the sitemap JS looks like, so you can get an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
Evergage.init({
    cookieDomain: "example.co.uk",
    trackerUrl: "https://example.germany-2.evergage.com"
}).then(() => {
    const config = {
        global: {
            listeners: [
                Evergage.listener('submit', 'form', (event) => {
                    Evergage.sendEvent({
                        action: 'Account Created',
                        user: { 
                            attributes: {
                                emailAddress: event.detail,
                                signupReferralSource: '' /* ??? */
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })
            ]
        },
        pageTypes: [
            {
                name: "example",
                isMatch: () => true
            }
        ]
    };

    Evergage.initSitemap(config);
});
```